# How to mock interceptors?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, quarkus

How to mock interceptor methods during test?

Example of class with interceptor:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {


    @Override
    @MyAnnotation
    public Uni<List<SomeDto>> getAll() {
        return //
    }
```

Example of interceptor which works via @MyAnnotation:

```
@Priority(100)
@MyAnnotation
@Interceptor
public class MyInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object someMethod(InvocationContext ic)throws Exception {
       // some logic
        return ic.proceed();
    }

}
```

How test should be designed to mock invocation of someMethod in MyInterceptor?

```
@QuarkusTest
class SomeServiceTest {

    @Test
    void getAllNotBlacklisted() {
       // ???
    }
```

Comment: What's the use case for mocking an interceptor?

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Interceptors have logic, sometimes complex logic, and the benefits of testing them are the same as testing any other piece of code! And indeed, there is no facility that I know of to help with that, at least in the JEE world. What I do is (a) create a dummy bean only for tests - the bean has one method that records whether it was called, and maybe its arguments, and getters for the arguments (b) apply the interceptor to that method and (c) test. It is cumbersome, but at least it works.

Comment: An example from my own code [here](https://github.com/nikospara/realworld-v2/blob/master/realworld-v2-article-module/realworld-v2-article-services/src/test/java/realworld/article/services/authz/impl/ArticleServiceAuthorizerTest.java). It is for a *decorator* and using *weld-junit*, but the principle is the same.